# FindBugs does not detect SQL injection

Tags: java, hibernate, gradle, findbugs

I have a encountered a case where FindBugs did not detect SQL injection on my project. Project is built using Gradle and FindBugs plugin is used. I am using hibernate to connect to DB. Below is the section that contains SQL injection,

```
public List<String> fetchApplicationRequests(String applicationId,
        String fromDate, String toDate) throws ParseException {
    String sb = "SELECT * FROM table where applicationid = " + applicationId;
    Query query = getCurrentSession().createQuery(sb);
    query.setParameter("appId", applicationId);
    return (List<String>) query.list();
}
```

Clearly the above section shows an SQL injection. When I ran the same project using Veracode, it showed SQL injection for the section I have mentioned. Below is the FindBugs plugin section under my `build.gradle`.

```
apply plugin: "findbugs"

findbugs {
  toolVersion = '3.0.1'
  effort = "max"
  ignoreFailures = true
  findbugsTest.enabled = false
}
tasks.withType(FindBugs) {
  reports {
      xml.enabled = false
      html.enabled = true
 }
}
```

When I ran the commmand:

```
> ./gradlew clean build
```

It showed a list of bugs identified in my project under `build/reports/findbugs/main.html`

Below is the list of errors detected by FindBugs,

- Bad practice Warnings - 6
- Correctness Warnings - 17
- Internationalization Warnings - 31
- Malicious code vulnerability Warnings - 52
- Performance Warnings - 15
- Dodgy code Warnings - 46

I expect SQL injection which comes under **Security category** which is not detected,

[Bug description: FindBugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/bugDescriptions.html#SQL_NONCONSTANT_STRING_PASSED_TO_EXECUTE)

How can this be fixed or is there any other way I can detect SQL injection in my project?

Comment: I don't think there is any chance for SQL injection here. If something strange is passed in the String parameters the formatter will throw an exception and the whole method fails. If a valid date literal is passed, the result of it can't possibly contain any exploitable code.

Comment: What input would you expect to result in SQL-injection? Note that you are running the input through a `DateFormat` (at least I assume that's what `formatter` is) and unless you receive the pattern as input as well you should be on the safe side.

Comment: @piet.t Let us consider the date fields for input is in right format. The formatter formats based on "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss".

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name But Veracode showed as a SQL injection vulnerability and that was crirical.

Comment: Then Veracode is over cautious and doesn't take the fact into account that the parameter is passed onto a function that returns a very well defined result. How exactly should any exploitable code in the input parameter survive the conversion from a string to a date back to a string?

Comment: @Aravinth So how would your formatter-output ever contain something like a `'` that would an attacker to cut the string-literal short? In general, `PreparedStatements` should be preferred over string-concatenation for various reasons, but in your exact case the danger of SQL-injection isn#t one of them.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, I can say this is a SQL injection because when you refer this **query.setParameter("appId", applicationId);** and when user passes <"somestring OR 1=1"> this will result in whole set output and gives a false result, right?

Comment: @piet.t please refer the comment section above.

Comment: When I changed the section to `public List<String> fetchApplicationRequests(String applicationId,
  String fromDate, String toDate) throws ParseException {
 String sb = "SELECT * FROM table where aId = " + applicationId;
Query query = getCurrentSession().createQuery(sb);
 return (List<String>) query.list();
}`. This also does not shows error.

Comment: @Aravinth well, the code you posted in your edited is a completely different story than the one you posted earlier. The former is prone to SQL-injection while the latter isn't. If you now understand why (as you obviously didn't before) you have learned a valuable lesson.

Comment: Well you changed your code completely from the initial question. The **current** code shown is indeed vulnerable to SQL injection. The original  code was not

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yes I get, but still when I run findbugs it is not showing why?

Comment: @piet.t please refer above comment.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade to SpotBugs 3.1.7 and findsecbugs-plugin-1.8.0.jar. You then get

```
This use of org/hibernate/Session.createQuery(Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/hibernate/Query; can be vulnerable to SQL/HQL injection
```

for the line

```
Query query = ...
```

(And then rewrite your code, of course :) )